# Implementing code as a shader in Processing 3

Tags: processing, shader

I recently created a simple program in Processing 3 to set each pixel to its position as a color.

```
void setup()
{
  size(960,960);
}

void draw()
{
  for(int j = 0;j < height;j++)
  {
    for(int i = 0;i < width;i++)
    {
      set(i,j,color(map(i,0,width,0,255),map(j,0,height,0,255),0));
    }
  }
}
```

How would I be able to implement this as a shader?

Note: I've already looked online and couldn't really find an answer for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not very familiar with shaders yet, you should first take a look at this page: https://processing.org/tutorials/pshader/

What you'll probably want is to draw a rectangle that covers the entire screen, and use the built-in GLSL variable `gl_FragCoord`, which gives you the index of the current pixel in `x` and `y` much like your loop variables `i` and `j`. See https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml for full documentation

Also keep in mind that the values output by the fragment shader are in the range *0 to 1* instead of *0 to 255*. So in the end the relevant shader code might look something like:

```
uniform vec2 windowSize; //the shader doesn't know this automatically, so you'll need to pass it in yourself
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(gl_FragCoord / windowSize, 0, 1);
}
```